# When resizing a WPF window, how to control what gets folded first

Tags: wpf, window

I'm building a WPF app with a lot of controls on it. The requirement i'm facing is to control what gets folded/unfolded first when a user resizes the window (width-wise).
I'm trying to find out if there's a certain way I should layout my controls, to get this functionality "for free" - meaning not having to hook into the WM_SIZE and WM_GETMINMAXINFO messages and handle this manually -- ouch painful.

Here's a simple example:

```
<Window x:Class="DeleteMe.Window8"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="Window8" Height="150" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="220" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="0" >
        <Button Width="50" Height="50" Content="Btn1"/>
        <Button Width="50" Height="50" Content="Btn2"/>
        <Button Width="50" Height="50" Content="Btn3"/>
        <Button Width="50" Height="50" Content="Btn4"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="1">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        </Grid>
        <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="1" Height="Auto" Fill="Gray"/>
        <Border Grid.Column="0" Margin="5" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent" Height="100" Width="100">
            <Image Source="/heart_on.png"/>
        </Border>
        <Grid Grid.Column="1">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Margin="10,10,0,0" Text="TEXT1"/>
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Margin="10,5,0,0" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="TEXT2"/>
                <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Orientation="Vertical" >
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,2">
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="TEXT3:" />
                        <TextBlock Margin="2,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="TEXT4"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="TEXT5:" />
                        <TextBlock Margin="2,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="TEXT6"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
            <Grid Grid.Row="2" >
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                    <Grid Margin="7" Width="270" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5,0" Text="0" />
                        <Slider Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="Auto" Margin="5,0,5,0" Value="0" Minimum="0"/>
                        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="2" Margin="5,0" Text="1" />
                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>                       
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="2" Width="Auto">
        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center">
                Some other controls in here ...
            </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

More specifically, I need the image to fold first when shrinking the window, then the "Some other controls in here..." part and the whole TEXT's part should collapse equally.
The left side should always be visible, but I'm already doing that by setting the MinWidth of the whole window.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you need a [WrapPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.wrappanel.aspx), this panel stacks like a StackPanel, but wraps around to a new row or columns if there is not enough space.

Comment: I'm trying to find a way to control what gets folded (ie hidden). So in the example above, what you start shrinking the window, the first thing that gets folded in is the image.
The WrapPanel will not hide the image, it will try to make a new row or column for it, as you mention.